# Filtering nested lists and list items in Scala sudoku generator

Tags: scala, sudoku

As part of a sudoku generator, I have a function intended to filter nested lists in order to return only inner lists of certain indices and inner list elements of certain indices within those lists. The idea is to return a List[Int] containing the values of a 3x3 square taken from a 9x9 sudoku puzzle represented as a List[List[Int]], which is provided as an argument to the function.

I have tried two approaches but have not been able to get either to work consistently. One approach attempts to filter out certain sublists from the list, and then filters out items from the remaining lists. This function works completely with some indices, but with others it will filter too many or too few index values from some sublists, but not all:

```
def getGroup(indexX: Int, indexY: Int, puzzle: List[List[Int]]): List[Int] = {
  val groupX = { //determining row coordinate
  if(indexX <= 2) 2
  else if(indexX <= 5) 5
  else 8
  }
  val groupY = { //determining column coordinate
  if(indexY <= 2) 2
  else if(indexY <= 5) 5
  else 8
  }
  // Using filter
  val subsection: List[List[Int]] = puzzle.filter(x => puzzle.indexOf(x) <= groupX && puzzle.indexOf(x) >= groupX - 2) 
  // This sometimes filters out too many or too few items
  val group: List[List[Int]] = subsection.map(x => x.filter(y => x.indexOf(y) <= groupY && x.indexOf(y) >= groupY - 2))

  val result = group.flatten
  println("subsection " + subsection)
  println("group " + group)
  result
}
```

Here is some output from a test List[List[Int]], with printing to show the results along the way. It isn't apparent to me why incorrect indices are filtered out from some sublists but not all on the same function call. I don't think I've simply selected the wrong indices or else it should be incorrect in the same manner for all sublists on the same function call.

```
test: List[List[Int]] = List(List(0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), List(2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), List(3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), List(4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), List(5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), List(6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), List(7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), List(8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))

scala> getGroup(2,2,test)
subsection: List(List(0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), List(2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
group: List(List(0, 2, 3), List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 2, 3))
res12: List[Int] = List(0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3) //Correct 

scala> getGroup(2,7,test)
subsection: List(List(0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), List(2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
group: List(List(7, 8, 9), List(7, 8, 9), List(7, 8, 9))
res13: List[Int] = List(7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9) //Correct 

scala> getGroup(7,7,test)
subsection: List(List(6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), List(7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), List(8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
group: List(List(7, 8, 9), List(8, 9), List(7, 9)) //Missing a 7 and an 8
res14: List[Int] = List(7, 8, 9, 8, 9, 7, 9) 

scala> getGroup(4,0,test)
subsection: List(List(3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), List(4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), List(5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
group: List(List(3, 2, 3), List(4, 2, 3, 4), List(5, 2, 3, 5)) //Not enough values filtered out--unwanted 4 and 5
res32: List[Int] = List(3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5)
```

This other approach uses a for loop which will only yield the values which fit the if conditions:

```
def getGroup(indexX: Int, indexY: Int, puzzle: List[List[Int]]): List[Int] = {
         //this portion is the same as above until the for expression:
  val groupX = { //determining row coordinate
    if(indexX <= 2) 2
    else if(indexX <= 5) 5
    else 8
  }
  val groupY = { //determining column coordinate
   if(indexY <= 2) 2
   else if(indexY <= 5) 5
   else 8
 }
    // using for expression
    val group = for(
      outer <- puzzle if puzzle.indexOf(outer) <= groupX && puzzle.indexOf(outer) >= groupX - 2; 
      inner <- outer if outer.indexOf(inner) <= groupY && outer.indexOf(inner) >= groupY - 2) 
        yield inner
  group
}
```

I have tested this function with this List[List[Int]], in which each list begins with its index number and just counts up thereafter:

```
val testGrid = List(List(0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),List(2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
List(3,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),List(4,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),List(5,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
List(6,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),List(7,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),List(8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))
```

However, the output is not always correct:

```
scala> getGroup(0, 0, testGrid)
res0: List[Int] = List(0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3) (correct)
scala> getGroup(3,3,testGrid)
res1: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 4, 6) (too few)
scala> getGroup(3,7,testGrid)
res2: List[Int] = List(7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9) (correct)
scala> getGroup(7,7,testGrid)
res3: List[Int] = List(7, 8, 9, 8, 9, 7, 9) (too few)
scala> getGroup(7,0,testGrid)
res5: List[Int] = List(6, 2, 3, 6, 7, 2, 3, 7, 8, 2, 3, 8) (too many)
```

There could be an obvious answer for why I'm getting this output, but it has escaped me. I suspect that it has to do with the inner loop since all the tests with an indexY lower than 3 are correct, regardless of the value for indexX.

I would appreciate any feedback on either of these attempts. I would also appreciate any thoughts on an alternative approach which could make this function more intuitive or concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.slice` to filter a section of a list by indexes. Then `.map(x => x.slice(...))` to do the same with the inner lists, and finally `.flatten` to transform a `List[List[A]]` into a `List[A]`. All together:

```
def getGroup(indexX: Int, indexY: Int, puzzle: List[List[Int]]): List[Int] = {
  val xStart = indexX / 3 * 3
  val yStart = indexY / 3 * 3
  puzzle.slice(xStart, xStart + 3).map(row => row.slice(yStart, yStart + 3)).flatten
}
```